# Why do likes for comments come only for one day?

Tags: youtube

Recently I noticed one strange thing: likes for my comments came only till midnight, then number of likes didn't change at all. Here is [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMBFSGVi1c&lc=UgyquAr_ntW5RzmlJ214AaABAg) of the examples. I posted it yesterday, and I got 895 likes. As you can see, it's *Marvel Studios' Avengers: Endgame - Official Trailer* which is very popular and I should have got at least one like. It's not the only example, I have these problems with all my comments. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear but, here are my answers, your video might of  have lost popularity after one day.  Here is some info on likes,comments etc. for computer. Post comments on a video
Public videos

All comments on public videos on YouTube are public and anyone can reply to a comment that you post. If you're a Google Apps account user, any comment you post on YouTube is publicly visible to users outside of your domain.

To add a comment, just type in the "Share your thoughts" or "Add a comment" box under the video, then select Post.

You can no longer see any private comments on public videos.
Private videos
Comments are not available on private videos. If you want to allow comments on a video that's not publicly available, post an unlisted video instead.

Unlisted videos
You can comment and reply to comments on unlisted videos. Comments on unlisted videos can be seen by anyone who has the link to the video. Learn more about unlisted videos and privacy settings.

If you don't have a YouTube channel, by posting a comment you'll automatically create a channel. You can access and manage your channel by going to your account icon after posting your comment.
Reply to comments
Click Reply beneath a comment.
Type in your comment.
Click Reply.
Add formatting to comments
Subscribe to our YouTube Help channel to get the most out of YouTube. 
Add style to your comment
You can use rich text to format your comment with common special tags, such as:

*bold text* → bold
*italicized text* → italics
-strikethrough text- → strikethrough
Add links to your comment
If you add a URL to your comment, it will show as a hyperlink.

Add hearts to favorite comments
You can use a heart  to show appreciation for a viewer's comments on your Community tab comments, in addition to comments on the watch page.

Sign in to YouTube.
Navigate to a Community tab post.
Look for the  icon next to the thumbs up / thumbs down icons.
Viewers will see your avatar with a small red heart on the lower left and receive a notification (depending on viewer opt-in settings on desktop and mobile) that a channel owner "loves your comment."

Tip: You can also manage comments with the Creator Studio app on your mobile device. Get started in the YouTube Creator Studio app Help Center.
Access to Discussion tab

The Community tab replaces the Discussion tab. Comments from the Discussion tab can be accessed in the activity log and will be available for 30 days after your account gets access to the Community tab.

To access the activity log:

Open the YouTube app and sign in to YouTube.
Go to www.youtube.com/comments.
Pin comments to the top
You can pin comments to the top of the comments section to program what comment your fans see first when viewing your content. You can choose to pin your own comment or a fan comment.

Sign in to YouTube.
In the comments below a video, select the comment you want like to pin.
Click the menu icon More Menu > Pin. If you've already pinned a comment, this will replace it.
Note: You can Unpin a comment at any time. The comment will be moved back to the original position.
Click the blue button to confirm. On the pinned comment, you'll see a "Pinned by" icon.
Viewers will see this comment at the top of the watch page with the "Pinned by" icon and your channel name.

You can currently use this feature on YouTube comments. It will also be available soon on the Community tab.
Tip: You can also manage comments with the Creator Studio app on your mobile device. Get started in the YouTube Creator Studio app Help Center.
Like or dislike comments
Go to a comment, then use the Like  or Dislike  icon.

Tip: If you see a comment that you think is inappropriate, you can flag it as spam or abuse. If you're a creator, you can also use the comment moderation tools to manage comments on your videos.

Edit or remove your comment
Hover over the top-right of your comment.
Click the arrow that appears.
Choose Edit or Remove this comment.

Comment: The thing is that I have these problems with **all** my comments.

Comment: The popularity might just reduce overnight.